# Listing a renamed company on a resume or in a cover letter

Tags: resume, cover-letter

I had worked for a company that changed its name. In my résumé and cover letter should I just use the new name or should I mention the old one too? This wasn't an acquisition or anything, simply a change in name.I guess one must periodically check the names of past employers to make sure of their name.

Answer (score 42):

In a cover letter: "During my time at XYZ Corporation (formerly ABC, Inc)..."

In a resume:
SuperAwesomeWorker, XYZ Corporation (formerly ABC, Inc), 2008 - 2010

I wouldn't worry about going too far down the list of entries on your resume to correct names of companies, *unless* it will cause confusion when people attempt to verify employment and find all the paperwork/emails/calls come from XYZ Corporation and you listed only the name ABC Inc.

Comment: Agreed .. or, alternatively, "ABC, Inc. (now known as XYZ Corporation)".

Comment: @Carson63000 Right!

Comment: @Carson63000: I guess "ABC Inc. (now a part of XYZ Corp.)" would be appropriate if XYZ acquired ABC.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to mention the name first which is more well known. I.e. if company has made some big/successful product before name change, I'd go with _ABC corp (now XYZ)_ and on the contrary.

Comment: Good point, but in my case this would get pretty silly fast... "In my time at ABC (formerly XYZ, XYZ bought out DEF (making it XYZ DEF), DEF and XYZ were then bought out by ABC, then it was ABC: XYZ DEF, then ABC said 'enough' and just rebranded everything as ABC and forbid companies from appending XYZ or DEF)." I've been just putting "ABC" on my resume... IMO it's probably better to not start up the whole story behind that on a resume or cover letter.

Comment: As I commented below, if it is a company that just chose to rename and rebrand itself independently, then it is essentially the same company and you might as well use the new name since that would probably be more recognizable. However, if it was an acquisition (especially by a big company like Google) then it could be misleading.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [jcmeloni's excellent points](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/15062/148), I think it's worth mentioning that you should not worry about changes to the name of a company *before* or *after* you were working for them, just the name or names of the company *while you were working for them*.

There is absolutely nothing to be gained by updating your resume to say that you worked for XYZ Corp if it was only known as ABC, Inc while you were working there. In fact, it could be considered dishonest to do so. If you worked for a startup, which was acquired by (say) Google after you left, it would be a lie to say that you worked for Google.

Comment: Good point about dishonesty and I think that depends on the nature of the name change. If it is a company that just chose to rename and rebrand itself independently, then it is essentially the same company and you might as well use the new name since that would probably be more recognizable. However, if it was an acquisition (especially by a big company like Google) then it would be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a blank check to put any of the names, I advise you to put the most respected name, or the one helps you get the interview. And mention others in parenthesis after, or mention them in face-to-face interviews only.

Answer (score -2):

To the thought of "dishonest" discussion.  I would agree, but the original response said to included "formerly".  This is hardly dishonest.  In fact the exact opposite, if a company is doing a search on the OLD name, they might not find it, assume you do not know how to write a resume or are lying etc.  Yes dishonest if you leave out the "formerly" part.

Comment: Welcome to [workplace.se]! This looks more like a reply to [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/75200/33983) rather than an answer on its own. Please have a look at the [tour] and the Help Center article [answer].