# What should I call a university on my CV, if the university has recently changed names?

Tags: resume

The university I studied at has recently (a few months ago at the time of writing) changed its name.

When including my degree from this university on my CV, what should I put? The name on my degree, the current name, or perhaps both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In résumé/cover letter what to put if company changed its name?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/in-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-cover-letter-what-to-put-if-company-changed-its-name)

Comment: @gnat I did wonder this myself, but eventually decided that the added complication of my degree being an official document in the University's old name was enough of a differentiator - in my opinion there's also more "prestige" built around a university's name than that of a company. Of course, I'll accept it if the community decides otherwise!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both. With the old name in parentheses.

You want to avoid confusion, so give them all the information they need. This is the same way you would handle a company name change. Sometimes the name change is simple: College to University. Other times it more complex.

Comment: I think it also depends on how recent the name change is. I graduated 38 years ago and the college changed its name more than 10 years ago. I go with the current name now.

Comment: you could put "nee {old name}" in brackets, if you wanted to use a fancy term that is somewhat applicable!

Comment: I wouldn't use nee (or née) - universities aren't born - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_at_birth

Comment: Just something like "University of FizzBuzz (formerly University of FooBar)" is fine I think.