# Complicated working experience on LinkedIn

Tags: resume, linkedin

I would like to ask, how would you deal with this *not that important* situation, that I am dealing with right now.

I was working for one corporate for year and a half now and I would like to place this experience on my LinkedIn. However there is a little problem with that.

I originally came to company **Example Industries LLC**. Our department was moved to child company **Example Salesmen LLC** after couple of months for legal purposes. This change changed literally nothing for me. I stayed on the same position, office even the same chair.

I will be leaving the company now, but after couple of weeks there will be merge with another company (owned by same corporation) so the companies names (both of them, parent and child) will be changed to **Example Sample Industries LLC** and **Example Sample Salesmen LLC**.

What would be the best way to place this on my LinkedIn?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing a renamed company on a resume or in a cover letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/listing-a-renamed-company-on-a-resume-or-in-a-cover-letter)

Answer (score 3):

Just put the name of the company as it was when you were hired. Whatever name changes, mergers, splits, etc. occurred after you were hired don't matter as it relates to your work experience. It has nothing to do with you and it's not a reflection on you or your work experience.

If your job, or title, or duties changed as a result of any of this activity then list that, but you don't need to say that "Company X changed it's name to Company Y and then they merged with Company Z."... or whatever the case is.

Comment: If you want a reference from that company make sure the contact information is correct, but otherwise what happen to the name of the company, is something you shouldn’t concern yourself with.  It might matter if you were an officer of the company, but for entirely different reasons, successful mergers would be a selling point (I.e something you should foot stomp)

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of answers about how you should do this on a resume but I think the fact that you're asking about LinkedIn changes the advice since ideally your entry for your current job will link to your current company.

Assuming both entities have a LinkedIn presence that is well maintained by the company, I would use the *most recent version* of child company name:

1. That should be the version that actually exists on LinkedIn.
2. If they've set it up right, the child company's page will show as being affiliated with the parent company's page.
3. If they decide to create a new company page for the new name, then the old company page is going to stop getting updated and eventually get wiped/deleted.

To be clear, you shouldn't worry about name changes that happen well after you've left.

If only the parent company exists on LinkedIn, seek out co-worker's profiles to see how everyone else is doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The most important is to **provide the name of the company the same as it was when you worked there**.

---

If the company changed its name, and you want to show this, you might write:

> COMPANY_A, named COMPANY_B since *(date)*

or

> COMPANY_A, part of COMPANY_B since *(date)*

It is mostly irrelevant if the name changed WHILE you worked there, or AFTER. You are not forbidden to make a very short notice of that.

---

Alternatively, you can update your CV as:

> worked at COMPANY_A from ... to ...
>   worked at COMPANY_B from ... to ...

However, while correct, this might send the wrong message, that you left one job for another.Therefore, this could be tricky.

Comment: I totally agree with this. Working in tech we have this every day. A long time ago I worked with RedHat, which has recently been bought by IBM. I wouldn't be telling anyone that I worked for IBM, because I haven't -- that's a totally different thing.